# asp.net hosting/single domain/multiple application

Tags: iis, hosting

we have an domain for example www.testdomain.com.I have created a web application with the name **newapplication** and hosted like below

ie(www.testdomain.com/newapplication/default.aspx. its working fine.. again i created another webservice named **newapplication2** and hosted like www.testdomain.com/newapplication2/service.asmx  am facing the problem and getting the below error .As per my understanding
its not possible to host multiple asp.net application under single domain(www.testdomain.com)
correct me if am wrong.. and suggest some ideas how to acheive this?

Dev.

Comment: Please show the error message... and: it is absiolutely possible to host multiple ASP.NET applications within a single domain!

Comment: am not able to attch the img. am getting the below error message.   Server Application Unavailable

The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry your request.

Administrator Note: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server. Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.

Comment: and what does the event log say ?